# Angular2 build under angular-cli with directive and ng build --prod

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, autoscroll

I have an angular-cli app,

```
npm -v 3.10.8
node -v v6.9.1
angular2 ^2.4.0
angular/cli 1.0.0-beta.32.3
```

when I add to *package.json* this

```
"angular2-auto-scroll": "1.0.12"
```

[angular2-auto-scrol website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-auto-scroll)

and in *app.module.ts* import it

```
import { Angular2AutoScroll } from "angular2-auto-scroll/lib/angular2-auto-scroll.directive";
```

and add it to *declarations* section **ng build --prod** fails with this error

```
ERROR in Unexpected value 'Angular2AutoScroll in C:/coding/workspace/myapp/myapp-web/node_modules/angular2-auto-scroll/lib/angular2-auto-scroll.directive.d.ts' declared by the module 'AppModule in C:/coding/workspace/myapp/myapp-web/app_code/app/app.module.ts'
ERROR in ./app_code/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\coding\workspace\myapp\myapp-web\app_code'
 @ ./app_code/main.ts 6:0-74
 @ multi ./app_code/main.ts
```

however when I build with just ***ng build*** without *--prod* then all build fine. 
Does anyone know what could be the reason? Or any other way I can import this npm package so it does not fail PROD build?

Comment: Try `ng build --prod --aot false`, and see if that works. The library you are adding may not be AOT friendly. AOT = true is the default compilation mode for `prod` builds, has been since beta 28.

Comment: seems like it works without oat, Thanks a lot! The only consideration I have now is what would be the impact on performance of my app, is it big or not really?

Comment: The download times can become a factor, and the application will have to compile at run-time without AOT. It really comes down to the complexity of the application, internal/external audience, etc.. JIT is not bad, but if your application has the potential to become large, or have a large user base, AOT is really nice. What's sent to the client in bytes is a huge difference. AOT is a little work up front, though -> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with AOT compilation. AOT happens by default when using `--prod` flag.

take a look at the source code for [angular2-auto-scroll](https://github.com/NagRock/angular2-auto-scroll) That project defines one TS file in the [src/angular2-auto-scroll.directive.ts](https://github.com/NagRock/angular2-auto-scroll/blob/master/src/angular2-auto-scroll.directive.ts)

If you look at the [tsconfig.js file](https://github.com/NagRock/angular2-auto-scroll/blob/master/tsconfig.json) specifically  `"module": "commonjs"`. you'll see that the module this directive transpiles to is `commonjs`
If you look in your project under `C:/coding/workspace/myapp/myapp-web/node_modules/angular2-auto-scroll/lib/` you'll see a TS type definition `.d.ts`, a `.js` and a `.map` file. the js file is a `commonjs` module.

AOT does not like `commonjs` modules, you can research that on your own, it needs either an `es5` or `es6` module.

**All that said, here are some options to fix it**

- Copy the directive TS file from the source github [angular2-auto-scroll.directive.ts](https://github.com/NagRock/angular2-auto-scroll/blob/master/src/angular2-auto-scroll.directive.ts)  to your prject and remove the dependency.
- **or** you can make a pull request to the repo asking to change the `"module": "commonjs"` to `"module": "es6"` note: I opened an issue for it [here](https://github.com/NagRock/angular2-auto-scroll/issues/5)
- **or** if you do not care for aot, (which is highly recommended btw), you can cancel it by running `build`command with `--aot=false` [read here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#options) on build options

hope this helps.

Resources on AOT:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1732

Comment: really good answer, I'll use first option that you recommended (not sure what else has to be copied)

Comment: it's a solo ts file that only depends on angular, which you have in your project. should be as easy as copy-paste. let me know if you still see issues.

Comment: but what about the second file? we have there two files: _angular2-auto-scroll.directive.d.ts_ and _angular2-auto-scroll.directive.d.ts_

Comment: ok, I understand. It should be this file https://github.com/NagRock/angular2-auto-scroll/blob/master/src/angular2-auto-scroll.directive.ts and not those that I downloaded through NPM

Comment: Yes, you are correct. there is only one source file. All other files are *generated* by the typescript transpiler. Just copy the TS file from the github repo to your project and import it like you would a directive you wrote yourself. Also, add a comment with a credit to the author of that repo and a link to it ;)