# ng build -prod returns error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'am using angular cli to build and run an angluar2 App.

When I run: `ng server` everything goes fine. But when I run `ng build -prod` it throws error:

```
ERROR in Unexpected directive 'ObservableComponent in /Users/projectName/Dev02/dashboard-app/src/app/book/observable.component.ts' imported by the module 'BookComponent in /Users/projectName/Dev02/dashboard-app/src/app/book/book.component.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/projectName/Dev02/dashboard-app/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Here is the code for observable.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { BookService } from '../_service/book.service';
import { Book } from './book';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-observable',
   templateUrl: 'observable.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['observable.component.css']
})


export class ObservableComponent implements OnInit { 

    constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.fetchBooks();
    }

}
```

and book.component.ts:

```
import {NgModule, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ObservableComponent } from './observable.component';
import { PromiseComponent } from './promise.component';

@Component({
    template:  `
                <div class="wrapper-obervable-pormise">
                <div class="wrapper-observable">
                    <app-observable></app-observable>
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper-promise">
                    <app-promise></app-promise>
                </div>
                </div>
             `,
    styleUrls: ['./book.component.css']
})

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ObservableComponent,
        PromiseComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        ObservableComponent,
        PromiseComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        ObservableComponent,
        PromiseComponent
    ]
})

export class BookComponent {}
```

Any Idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Unexpected directive 'ObservableComponent imported by book component can you list them

Comment: @Rahul Singh: what should I list? don't really understand. But I found a kind of workaround here: [Angular build under Angular cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166491/angular2-build-under-angular-cli-with-directive-and-ng-build-prod/43172360)
`ng build -prod --aot=false`

Comment: Observable component and  Book

Comment: @Rahul Singh: added

Comment: Is it a shared module

Comment: What does this mean for the issues? Can you specify please?

Comment: Remove `ObservableComponent` from `imports` array

Comment: I think, you do not have to import `ObservableComponent`, declaration should be enough.

Comment: @yurzui, @ulubeyn: didn't solve the issue. New error comes up:

`ERROR in Type ObservableComponent in... observable.component.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules:.... Please consider moving ObservableComponent in... /book/observable.component.ts to a higher module that imports BookComponent in..../app/app.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes ObservableComponent in..../book/observable.component.ts then import that NgModule in BookComponent in...`

Comment: You have to declare this component only in one module. Other modules should import this module

Comment: I think the issue is fixed now. But other one comes up and it's a kind of confusing. I do have a component which I'am not using at all in none of the modules. It's just there setting in the file system (I used it before for some testing). But now when I run: `ng build -prod` I get the error: 
`ERROR in Cannot determine the module for class SecureStuffComponent in...`. If delete it, it throws further errors.

Comment: Issue fixed. All your comments guys were helpful to figure out what's wrong on my code. Indeed I had some wrong declarations, Imports etc. in the module(s) and the components etc. I can run `ng build -prod` without issues.
Just one thing more: How can I mark this question as solved as there is no answer... just comments - which did really help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NgModule.imports only accepts modules; not components.

You should therefore, remove `ObservableComponent` and `PromiseComponent` from the imports array.

E.g.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ObservableComponent,
        PromiseComponent
    ],
    imports: [],
    exports: [
        ObservableComponent,
        PromiseComponent
    ]
})
```

> **From Angular Docs:** The next section is where you configure the @NgModule by stating what components and directives belong to it (declarations) as well as which other modules it uses (imports). For more information on the structure of an @NgModule, be sure to read [Bootstrapping](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping).